# Explanation for slicing in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, slice

why is the output same every time?

```
a = torch.tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
a[-2:] = torch.tensor([[[5, 6]]])
a
```

tensor([0, 1, 2, 5, 6])

```
a = torch.tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
a[-2:] = torch.tensor([[5, 6]])
a
```

tensor([0, 1, 2, 5, 6])

```
a = torch.tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
a[-2:] = torch.tensor([5, 6])
a
```

tensor([0, 1, 2, 5, 6])

Answer (score 0):

Pytorch is following Numpy here which [allows assignment](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays) to slices as long as the shapes are compatible meaning that the two sides have the same shape or the right hand side is broadcastable to the shape of the slice. Starting with trailing dimensions, two arrays are [broadcastable](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) if they only differ in dimensions where one of them is 1. So in this case

```
a = torch.tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
b = torch.tensor([[[5, 6]]])
print(a[-2:].shape, b.shape)
>> torch.Size([2]) torch.Size([1, 1, 2])
```

Pytorch will perform the following comparisons:

1. `a[-2:].shape[-1]` and `b.shape[-1]` are equal so the last dimension is compatible
2. `a[-2:].shape[-2]` does not exist, but `b.shape[-2]` is 1 so they are compatible
3. `a[-2:].shape[-3]` does not exist, but `b.shape[-3]` is 1 so they are compatible
4. All dimensions are compatible, so  `b` can be broadcasted to `a`

Finally, Pytorch will convert `b` to `tensor([5, 6])` before performing the assignment thus producing the result:

```
a[-2:] = b
print(a)
>> tensor([0, 1, 2, 5, 6])
```